# how can I change default global bower setting?

Tags: bower

I know there is .bowerrc setting, but I don't like create it each time on my project; how can I change the default global bower directory setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bower will install the dependency in bower_components folder in the project root.
If you want to install in the custom path for all the projects, then place .bowerrc file in the global folder (/). For more details on .bowerrc file placement please check the bower documentation. 
http://bower.io/docs/config/#placement--order